# Sending decimals using radio.write(); with Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I'm adapting a sketch I found to send sensor data over a wifi chip (Nrf2401), and although I get the message through, the value I send contains decimals (e.g. 24.59), but the received message will only be 24.

I'm sure there's something wrong on the transmitter part of the code, but I can't see what.

Here's my code:

```
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

OneWire oneWire(4);

DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

// ce,csn pins
RF24 radio(8,7);

unsigned char data[3] = {
  0};
unsigned long count=0;
void setup(void)
{
  sensors.begin();  
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.println("**************V1 Send Sensor Data***********");
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.setChannel(0x4c);

  // open pipe for writing
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1LL);

  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  radio.setAutoAck(true);
  radio.powerUp();
  Serial.println("...Sending");
}

void loop(void)
{
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  float currentTemp;
  currentTemp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

  //assign 'T' to represent a Temperature reading
  data[0] = 'T';
  data[1] = currentTemp;
  count++;
  // print and increment the counter
  radio.write(data, sizeof(float)+1);
  Serial.print("Temperature sent:  ");
  Serial.println(currentTemp);
  // pause a second
  delay(500);
}
```

In this example, when I print currentTemp, it will display the decimals, but if I print data[1], it won't.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning `data [1] = currentTemp`. Current temp is a float, not a character so this won't work. Decimals are lost because the float will be cast to a char in the assignment. Make data into a larger buffer and use sprintf to print currentTemp if you want to use it as a string. Really you should be writing just currentTemp to the radio and formatting on the other end, which will make the operation faster and require less bandwith to transmit (not to mention that transmitting and formatting are different concerns and should be separated, not coupled, when possible).

Comment: I realized sending a float between machines probably isn't the best idea since there are different representations for them. Print it to a string and send it that way.